# Eliminar un elemento de una Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una `Collection` que me llega desde la ruta. Esta `Collection` tiene una relación, `detalle`, que es de donde quiero eliminar uno de los objetos que llega, exactamente el `"qdet_ref" => "300_1_2"`. En otro momento puedo querer eliminar otro u otros.

La Collection se llama `$cuestionario`; el detalle es `$cuestionario->detalle`

A continuación ambos pasados a Array para que se visualicen mejor:

**$cuestionario:**

```
array:18 [▼
  "quest_id" => 278
  "quest_paxid" => 450
  "quest_anyfiscal" => 2015
  "quest_pdfgenlink" => "assets/arfis_pdf/QUESTIONARI-278-aa4f86fe6f2aa0f317df4f5491620d53e428512a.pdf"
  "quest_pdfsiglink" => null
  "quest_usruid" => 42
  "quest_acceptat" => "A"
  "quest_costsc" => "10.50"
  "quest_estat" => "T"
  "quest_generat_ip" => "2147483647"
  "quest_na" => 5
  "quest_empresa_id" => 1
  "quest_rlid" => null
  "quest_edad" => 43
  "created_at" => "2016-06-02 10:43:32"
  "updated_at" => null
  "deleted_at" => null
  "detalle" => array:63 [▶]
]
```

**$detalle**

```
array:63 [▼
  0 => array:13 [▼
    "qdet_id" => 10302
    "qdet_ref" => "300_1_1"
    "qdet_resp" => "S"
    "qdet_quest_id" => 278
    "qdet_resp_json" => null
    "qdet_imp1" => "0.00"
    "qdet_imp2" => "0.00"
    "qdet_nombre" => null
    "qdet_orden" => 20
    "qdet_pes" => "0.00"
    "created_at" => "2016-06-02 10:43:32"
    "updated_at" => null
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  1 => array:13 [▼
    "qdet_id" => 10303
    "qdet_ref" => "300_1_2"
    "qdet_resp" => "N"
    "qdet_quest_id" => 278
    "qdet_resp_json" => null
    "qdet_imp1" => "0.00"
    "qdet_imp2" => "0.00"
    "qdet_nombre" => null
    "qdet_orden" => 40
    "qdet_pes" => "0.00"
    "created_at" => "2016-06-02 10:43:32"
    "updated_at" => null
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  2 => array:13 [▶]
  3 => array:13 [▶]
  4 => array:13 [▶]
...
]
```

He mirado todos los métodos disponibles en Laravel para trabajar con una `Collection`, he probado alguno de ellos y no he conseguido lo que pretendo con ninguno de ellos. El, para mi, más evidente `pull()` que elimina un elemento por su clave:

```
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk']);

$collection->pull('name');

// 'Desk'

$collection->all();

// ['product_id' => 'prod-100']
```

[Documentación oficial Laravel-Español: pull()](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pull)

Pero cuando lo aplico:

```
$detalle->pull('300_1_2');
```

No hace absolutamente nada; devuelve lo mismo que antes de hacerlo.
¿Qué es lo que no estoy haciendo bien o qué alternativa tengo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar filter() para mantener los demás elementos de la colección:

```
$nuevoDetalle = $detalle->filter(function ($item) {
    if ($item->qdet_ref != '300_1_2') {
        return $item;
    }
});
```

También lo puedes lograr con where() y otros métodos que hay disponibles.

Comment: Lo usé y no funcionaba; pero no lo hice como lo explicas tú, con callback.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres hacer es eliminar un atributo / componente de una colección lo que tienes que hacer es:

`unset($detalle['300_1_2']); // en caso de que sea array`

O bien

`unset($detalle->300_1_2); // en caso de que sea objeto`

Comment: En el caso de objeto, que es lo que tengo, no funciona. En todo caso, gracias.